# Two virtually identical bibtex entries, one cites the other not (Overleaf User)

Tags: citing, natbib, overleaf

And even funnier, in the MWE I produced for SE they both cite. I cannot reproduce the error in the MWE, in the document only `WorldBank2017`works, while `WorldBank2012` is suggested to me as a key when I start typing `\citep{`, but if I complete the citation and compile it only gives question mark with the corresponding error

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `WorldBank2012' on page 6 undefined on input line 125
```

Any ideas why this could be?

**Not an MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\title{Stackexchange}
\date{July 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The world development report \citep{WorldBank2012}. And another one \citep{WorldBank2017}

\bibliography{bib.bib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}


\end{document}
```

**Bib file**

```
@techreport{WorldBank2012,
address = {Washington D.C.},
author = {{World Bank}},
institution = {World Bank},
pages = {},
series = {World Development Report},
title = {{Gender Equality and Development}},
url = {https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/handle/10986/4391},
year = {2012}
}

@techreport{WorldBank2017,
address = {Washington D.C.},
author = {{World Bank}},
institution = {World Bank},
pages = {06--20},
series = {1},
title = {{Maharashtra - Poverty, growth, and inequality}},
url = {https://documents.worldbank.org/en/publication/documents-reports/documentdetail/806671504171811149/maharashtra-poverty-growth-and-inequality},
year = {2017}
}
```

**Update**

It does seem to cite the entry, just enters a question mark instead of the author-year format. Indeed, the reference entry also misses the author name.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the issue. By the way, it should be `\bibliography{bib}` without the `.bib` extension.

Comment: Can it be the case that you have both files `bib.bib.bib` and `bib.bib` in the same directory and the system used the first file while you expected the second?